# UITextView cutting off text mid-line

Tags: ios

UITextView is cutting off text in the middle of a line. Screenshot (intentionally large so the issue is visible):

[image]

The bottom part of the [] characters is being chopped off, as are the characters in the words "bear it" (most visible on the 'a'). The text is being rendered with an NSAttributedString and setting the paragraphSpacing style appears to do nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Make the UITextView taller?

Comment: Tried a different font? I have seen defective fonts to render that exact effect (sometimes on top, sometimes at the bottom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had something to do with `NSParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore`. When I set the before paragraph spacing back to 0, the problem disappeared. I used `UITextView.contentInset` as a workaround to implement padding at the top of the view.